# Look up my current userID with mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This scripts selects an account form my MySQL database with the `userID` 1:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;
```

If my MySQL account has id 1 then it will change that account.
I wonder how you can change the = 1; so it automatically looks up which account you are on at the moment? Right now it only works with the account with userID 1.

MySQL database name for my userid is "userID".

Comment: You should post the SQL code and user table structure as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using `Session` so it can not change the `userID` unless you destroy that session by using this PHP function:

```
session_destroy();
```

And if you want to know your current userID:

```
echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would say something like 
`SELECT * FROM user_profiles WHERE user_id=1` in MySQL.

Also, I would recommend that you use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) and properly escape the user input using 
`htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['user_id'])`
in your PHP file since the user_id input most likely can be manipulated by the user.